# Randomization in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

In VB.net, I have a function which generates a random string of integer numbers

```
Public Function RandomString(ByVal Size As Integer, ByVal LowerBound As Double, ByVal Upperbound As Double) As list (of integer)
```

It gets three factors (size, lowerBound and upperBound) and generates a random list of length "size" each value randomly between "LowerBound" and "UpperBound"

In my code at the top I have:

```
Imports System.Random
```

And the body of the function goes like this:

```
Dim rand As New Random
Dim mystr as new list (of integer)
for i as integer=1 to size
    mystr.add(rand.Next(Upperbound - LowerBound + 1) + LowerBound)
next
return mystr
```

Inside my sub I have:

```
dim MyData(10) as list (of integer)
for i as integer = 0 to 9
    mydata(i) = new list (of integer)
    mydata(i) = RandomString(5,2,4)
next
```

The strange problem is that when I run this normally , it generates 10 strings exactly the same values.

For example like this:

```
2,3,3,2,4
2,3,3,2,4
2,3,3,2,4
...
```

But when i put a toggle stop point inside the loop (loop inside my sub) and I run the code step by step, it work correctly and generates different strings as intended.
such as

```
2,3,2,4,3
3,2,4,4,2
4,3,3,2,2
...
```

Why does this happen? How should I modify it to work correctly in a normal run?

Comment: Move the *rand* variable outside of the method so it doesn't get initialized with the current time as a seed every time you call the method.

Comment: Or add `Randomize()` call at the beginning of the function

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vb.net Random Number generator generating same number many times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456477/vb-net-random-number-generator-generating-same-number-many-times)

Comment: No idea why that would be tricky, declaring it Shared or adding it to a Module is fine.  Even keeping it inside the function and declaring it Static works.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry - misread - thought you said move it out of the loop, not method

Answer (score 2):

When you create an instance of Random, if you don't pass the seed you wish to use, it will use a default one that is time dependent. From the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9.aspx):

> The default seed value is derived from the system clock and has finite resolution. As a result, different Random objects that are created in close succession by a call to the default constructor will have identical default seed values and, therefore, will produce identical sets of random numbers.

Which is why you get a "more random" result when you debug it - you are giving more time between instantiations.

So either [use different seeds for each instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctssatww.aspx), or artificially give more time between each instantiation (i.e.: `Thread.Sleep`, but this is a very ugly hack).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, by default, `System.Random` will seed itself based off the current time.  If you create multiple instances in a very short period of time (such as a loop), you'll get the same seed, which will in turn create the same sequence.

You can avoid this by making your Random instance `Static`:

```
Public Function RandomString(ByVal Size As Integer, ByVal LowerBound As Double, ByVal Upperbound As Double) As List(of Integer)
    ' Static makes this instance get "preserved" across multiple calls to the method
    ' So it's only created once
    Static rand As New Random

    Dim mystr as new List(of Integer)
    For i as integer=1 to size
        mystr.add(rand.Next(Upperbound - LowerBound + 1) + LowerBound)
    next
    return mystr
End Function
```

This will cause the same instance to be used across multiple calls, which in turn will cause it to not re-seed with the same seed.  Note that this will not be thread safe, however, if you use this method from multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

@Renan's answer is correct.  You can also do the following, which initializes the variable only once but should give you uniqueness during multiple calls.

```
Static rand As New Random
```

Comment: +1, because for a simple task like what the OP is doing a single instance of `Random` will do. Straight to the point there, you went.