# Random number/letter generator not working correctly

Tags: vb.net, random

Hello all I am trying to figure out why my code below only produces the same random letters/number for all 4/5/8 varibles:

```
Public Function GenerateRandomString(ByRef iLength As Integer, Optional numberOnly As Boolean = False) As String
    If numberOnly Then
        Dim RandomClass As New Random()
        Dim RememberSet As New HashSet(Of Integer)
        Dim RandomNumber As Integer

        While RememberSet.Count < 3
            RandomNumber = RandomClass.Next(1, 3)

            If RememberSet.Add(RandomNumber) Then
                Return RandomNumber
            End If
        End While
    Else
        Dim rdm As New Random()
        Dim sResult As String = ""
        Dim allowChrs() As Char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLOMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".ToCharArray()

        For i As Integer = 0 To iLength - 1
            sResult += allowChrs(rdm.Next(0, allowChrs.Length))
        Next

        Return sResult
    End If
End Function
```

And this is the code that I use to test it out:

```
Private Sub testing()
   Dim fourValue1 As String = Nothing
   Dim fourValue2 As String = Nothing
   Dim fourValue3 As String = Nothing
   Dim twelveValue As String = Nothing
   Dim eightValue As String = Nothing

   fourValue1 = GenerateRandomString(4)
   fourValue2 = GenerateRandomString(4)
   fourValue3 = GenerateRandomString(4)
   twelveValue = GenerateRandomString(12)
   eightValue = GenerateRandomString(8)

   debug.print(fourValue1)
   debug.print(fourValue2)
   debug.print(fourValue3)
   debug.print(twelveValue)
   debug.print(eightValue)
End Sub
```

And this is what I get for the output for the above code:

```
Z4Gb
Z4Gb
Z4Gb
Z4Gb5Sq28VOr
Z4Gb5Sq2
```

So are you see **Z4Gb** is in each of the random generated variables and then **Z4Gb5Sq2** is within the **8** and **12** variables.

So what am I doing incorrect?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456477/vb-net-random-number-generator-generating-same-number-many-times

Comment: use a single Random instance (form/class level);  you are creating new ones in quick sucession.  With your code I get `iKd8` repeats, using the same RND instance, they are all different

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that each of the `new Random()` calls are getting the same seed. Create the Random object in the class constructor.

Comment: He is not using the old legacy VB Rnd function but the shiny new NET `Random` class which `Randomize` has no effect on

Comment: Ah yes. But the "shiny new" version uses a seed with a very low resolution.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx

Comment: The seed itself is both arbitrary and "high  resolution": the number of clock ticks since the last system restart. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/random.cs,bb77e610694e64ca

Comment: If that were the case, you wouldn't get this behavior, no?

Comment: See the "Avoiding multiple instantiations" content from my link above.