# Problem with random number generator Same Numbers

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem with a random number between two variables. It always gives me the same number between two numbers. Not a random numbers between two numbers.

```
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Randomize()
        Dim rnd As New Random
        Dim minval As Integer
        Dim maxval As Integer

        minval = 1000 / grempamin.Value
        maxval = 1000 / grempamax.Value

        Timer1.Interval = rnd.Next(maxval, minval)

        If MouseButtons = MouseButtons.Left Then
            apimouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            apimouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vb.net Random Number generator generating same number many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456477/vb-net-random-number-generator-generating-same-number-many-times)

Comment: I'd recommend pulling all of the "get random number" logic out into its own function. Then you can more easily test whether the "random" part isn't working, or if that part _is_ working but it's just not taking effect in the Timer. (Can you just change the timer interval like that? Or do you have to `Timer1.Stop()` first, _then_ change the interval, then `Timer1.Start()` again?)

Answer (score 1):

A few changes

```
Private Shared rnd As New Random  '<<<<<<<<<<<<<
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    'Randomize 'not needed  '<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    Dim minval As Integer
    Dim maxval As Integer

    minval = 1000 / grempamin.Value
    maxval = 1000 / grempamax.Value
    Timer1.Interval = rnd.Next(minval, maxval + 1) '<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    If MouseButtons = MouseButtons.Left Then
        apimouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        apimouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```

[Random Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

edit: per marks comment.  If there is a possibility that min and max are not min and max make this change to the rnd.next

```
    Timer1.Interval = rnd.Next(Math.Min(minval, maxval), Math.Max(minval, maxval) + 1) '<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

Comment: Your change to the `rnd.Next` method call (switching the OP's order of min and max) is probably going to result in a ArgumentOutOfRangeException being thrown. The way `minval` and `maxval` are being calculated probably results in the variable `minval` being equal or greater than `maxval`.

Comment: @MarkL - based on the info available how can you know that?

Comment: Presumably `grempamin < grempamax`, Dividing each of those into 1000 means that `minval > maxval`.  OP presumably encountered this previously, that's why their `rnd.Next` call is from max to min. So your update to call `rnd.Next` with min to max will probably throw the exception.

Comment: @MarkL - based on those assumptions I see your point.  Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

If `grempamin` and `grempamax` have values that are close to each other, then dividing them into 1000 can result in the same integer value. This may be what's happening in your code.

You haven't explained your code requirements very well, but I suspect that you're making some basic math errors here.

I think `grempamin` and `grempamax` have the min and max number of seconds, so since the timer interval is in milliseconds, you'd need to multiply by 1000.

If so, then your code sample might work better as this (including dbasnett's changes):

```
Private rnd As New Random
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim minval As Integer
    Dim maxval As Integer

    minval = 1000 * grempamin.Value
    maxval = 1000 * grempamax.Value

    Timer1.Interval = rnd.Next(minval, maxval)

    If MouseButtons = MouseButtons.Left Then
        apimouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        apimouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have numbers between 1 and 20  when I try with  * then it's not working. And I have Timer1.Start() and Timer1.Stop() with toggle button

Comment: and I also have this I don't know if this causes problems     `Private Sub grempamin_Scroll(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles grempamin.Scroll
        grempamincount.Text = grempamin.Value
        grempamax.Minimum = grempamin.Value + 1
        grempamaxcount.Text = grempamax.Value
    End Sub`

Comment: @Kaktus12 - what does 'not working' mean?  1 and 20 are where?