# Randomize numbers Visual Basic

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to figure out how to generate 3 different random numbers between 50 and 100 using visual basic. My code only prints out the same number three times.

```
Dim number As Integer
number = rndNumber.Next(50, 100)

lblATime.Text = number.ToString
lblBTime.Text = number.ToString
lblCTime.Text = number.ToString
```

Comment: Read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netcore-3.1). "However, on the .NET Framework only, because the clock has finite resolution, using the parameterless constructor to create different Random objects in close succession creates random number generators that **produce identical sequences of random numbers**."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vb.net Random Number generator generating same number many times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7456477/692942).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are storing a random number in `number` variable and displaying it three times.

If you want 3 different numbers, call it thrice

```
lblATime.Text = rndNumber.Next(50, 101).ToString
lblBTime.Text = rndNumber.Next(50, 101).ToString
lblCTime.Text = rndNumber.Next(50, 101).ToString
```

Also, from the docs,

> Next(minValue, maxValue) returns random integers that range from minValue to maxValue - 1. However, if maxValue equals minValue, the method returns minValue.

So, use Next(50, 101) if you want to include both 50 & 100.

Comment: It’s more likely using the same seed -"However, on the .NET Framework only, because the clock has finite resolution, using the parameterless constructor to create different Random objects in close succession creates random number generators that produce **identical sequences of random numbers**.".

Comment: @Lankymart While using the same seed is a common problem, the posted code is doing exactly what this answer says: taking one random number and displaying it three times.

Answer (score 2):

The line `number = rndNumber.Next(50, 100)` does NOT set up a "relation" between `number` and that expression, meaning it does NOT re-execute that expression every time you access `number`.

Rather, when the app reaches that line, it executes `rndNumber.Next(50, 100)` *once* and assigns the resulting (integer) value to the variable `number`. Until you assign something else, that `number` will keep its assigned value. That is why all three Text properties get the same value.